# SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats in django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to run the code.But none of the below commands working:

```
python manage.py runserver.
pyhton manage.py makemigrations
pyhton manage.py showmigrations
```

I am getting below error:

I am doing this in ubuntu

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/timetracker/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/timetracker/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.init_connection_state()
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 231, in init_connection_state
    if self.features.is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled:
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 82, in is_sql_auto_is_null_enabled
    cursor.execute('SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL')
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 312, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/zapbuild/ZapbuildProjects/timetracker/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 224, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats
```

My requirements.txt is:

I am not sure this is related to some python version and lib mismatch.

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
coreapi==2.3.3
coreschema==0.0.4
Django==2.2.1
django-coreapi==2.3.0
django-cors-headers==3.4.0
djangorestframework==3.10.3
idna==2.10
itypes==1.2.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
Pillow==6.0.0
python-decouple==3.3
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
uritemplate==3.0.1
urllib3==1.25.10
#numpy==1.18.5
#pandas==0.24.2
```

Please help. As None of the mentioned solutions seems to work.